# Provision a WAAD Tenant in code

Tags: .net, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

How can I provision a Windows Azure Active Directory tenant in code?

I'd like to be able to allow users to walk up to my Multi-Tenant SaaS application, sign-up for my service and be provisioned an Azure Active Directory Tenant for them to manage their users in my application.

I've looked at the Graph API and don't see where I can provision a separate Tenant per company.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, today creating a tenant programmatically is not an option.

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised that's not possible. I wonder how the other SaaS apps appear to do that.

Comment: They don't! :) Do you have an example of non-Microsoft app or service that creates a tenant programmatically?

Comment: No specific example. Just thinking out loud. Thanks for your help.